# How to fire a function in C# once data changes on SQL Server Table only when the table gets stable?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Scenario

- I have a database where real-time data is inserted. Ex. Price of Symbols.
- The data is inserted every 5 sec.(around 10000 rows each time) though some 3rd party tool

Things I have already tried:

- SQL Dependency which detects changes in the table and alerts me the changes are made.
- On change I fire fetching query
- Problem arises is that the connection pool gets full and throws a exception
- Thread sleep will be a problem since if rows insertion takes less time , still I will be waiting for fixed interval

What I want:

- My Web application to fetch the data once insertion gets stable i.e no more rows are inserted in a
  time-span of 1-2 sec.

Environment
C#-MCV, SQL Server

Comment: This is really something that should be handled in code. Is there a reason you need to wait? Triggers are very fast. I'd performance test a trigger on insert into the table, and propagate the needed updates out that way. This is the best way to ensure the data in the DB is consistent. Otherwise you can read stale data from some tables. If the performance is too slow, you might be able to improve it by setting appropriate indexes on the tables needing update.

Comment: Have a look at [this blog](https://nielsberglund.com/2017/02/11/rabbitmq---sql-server/) It's using RabbitMQ to publish the messages and uses SQLCLR to add custom .NET code to the SQL Engine. You can call the wrapped methods in a trigger.

Comment: Or use [ServiceBrokerListener](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener)